# How to speed up copying data from SSD to Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have two external drives. One SSD and one HDD both of them connected to a computer via USB 3.

Both drives are in NTFS and are brand new.

When copying data from the SSD to the HDD with the option "Optimize for performance" disabled, the speed is around 25 MB/s.

When I activate this option for both disks, the speed is around 300 MB/s during the first 3 seconds and then it drops to 25 MB/s which is very slow compared to the file size I need to transfer.

I'm trying to copy only one file of 100 GB size.

Does anyone know how to speed up this please ?

Comment: Your bottleneck is going to be that HDD.  You are likely saturating the USB connection due to the SSD but your designation is several factors slower than your SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your HDD is USB2.0 or the HDD case / USB adapter of the drive is USB2.0? All my external USB3.0 drives make at least 80MB/s and the faster ones over 100MB/s. The fast speed at the beginning of the copy operation is caused by a Windows write cache.

You can upgrade your HDD case / adapter cable to USB3.0 if the drive itself is a normal SATA drive.